# Why my Python function doesn't return the result?

Tags: python

I am trying to write a Python function which can return "True" or "False" in evaluating a magic square. A magic square is a matrix all of whose row sums, column sums and the sums of the two diagonals are the same. (One diagonal of a matrix goes from the top left to the bottom right, the other diagonal goes from top right to bottom left.)

Here is my code:

```
def isMagic(A3):
    dim = A3.shape[0] * A3.shape[1]
    construct = np.arange(1,dim+1)
    if A3.shape[0] == A3.shape[1]:
        exist = []
        for r in range(len(A3)):
            for c in range(len(A3)):
                exist.append(A3[r,c] in construct)
        if all(exist):
            def all_same(items):
                return all(x == items[0] for x in items)
            dig_1 = sum(np.diag(A3))
            dig_2 = sum(np.diag(np.fliplr(A3)))
            dig = all_same(np.array([dig_1, dig_2]))
            column = all_same(np.sum(A3, axis = 1))
            row = all_same(np.sum(A3, axis = 0).transpose())
            if all(dig, column, row):
                return True
            else:
                return False
```

Yet, when I try to test my code on one of the magic square, the function doesn't return any value:

```
test2 = np.matrix([[8, 1, 6],
              [3, 5, 7],
              [4, 9, 2]])
isMagic(test2) # True
```

I wondered that if it was because the indentation?

Comment: I guess there are nothing appended to **exist** list

Comment: Python functions always return a value.

Comment: The boolean values are appended to the list.

Comment: if all(exist):  -- this is returning False for some reason. Figure that out, and you will discover the reasons why your function returns None.

Comment: @beiller thanks! You are right. I am looking into it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your first two `if` statements `if A3.shape[0] == A3.shape[1]` and `if all(exist)`, notice if the condition is false, nothing (`None`) is returned. I guess you want to return False if all of your if conditions are not met. Then just put `return False` at the very end of the function so it is run if `return True` is not reached:

```
def isMagic(A3):
    ...
    return False
```

Comment: Thanks @qwr. I add "else return False" to each level of "If" statement. The function returns T/F now. Guess previously, function return "None" when the "If" statement doesn't meet since I didn't specify "else". Thanks again!